python jwe.decrypt c# equivalent?
I'm trying to decrypt a jwt token in .Net 6 without success.
DecriptionKey is PEM-encoded private key, something like this
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
                ...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"

what is the .net6 equivalent for this python code, that easily do the job?
from jose import jwe, jwt, jwk, jws
import base64
#from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
#from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

encrypted_jwe = "eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUC0yNTYiLCJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0.IDqmx1u_8Jd6XofUyTubUEAMWw9Zu2reF3JJsijRICCFRG_Dcb15pOs61DQx8DwhQbVSWA-Zbt_xlJ5dTtaC_JlP8PRFYbAkhHdOtPVUuEKIx9OEm5DOF5hi-d-VJd5JOrDaGgSSlz59vQHgY8whGzNTbJhfjyKwkz-uaEiyb8kblDAVd-mjBPcL1_1MOpMfyfuXgroi3RiR--zyjNgOUZ2R3hKZmlISAuRjrIJB8xKZntRu3GtJczX6jCgJFvWAYqrlHtMoRLuGrcOsM3WDx7urX9ur90A7idGuq2rj8aaOg2Ld-sAMfhoS0jKwK4Gj0CumAza4QvpZPVjVWaep7A.XlSCfsZVmku1CGxK.mCbCvPxsdWRDw_ZmlMtETrX_TLdxQQ0lxqFfUaX6Pv8TCChFodZb9PE0kUycW1pTTPYYbGh2d40CYgvLAMP_c1me27uFYOsy3P3CDoULKR-MNU4f19nCuRlMgWeMqG0e7GVmGQwem4TpcA4CZTdd5V0kzXBLm4ns3i3NlNoNrhfG7pW87Eb0oYo9s1wvALDmvgiFUb-apxUqJXaSIZ51pSSwkyPSLPtd_tq-8weNNuyf9SBsQUWEjRn8CHtmjuKhKOP4TaJYqjsA80ydLUUhmogrMzpqEgahitZ1ygDwv2UYwzykt5kklZ63OGPdZrYosM3t0kpi4CP9F5gyvx-jOiiMLcdz46d0t8315H9HEJW_Du3BkmW6IQ1r__mlrp2ylNMTVT7_oh_WQHUc2HEszJ-yELUSd0RM96vgXUGjWlwfex9hLYI2VaMSZ00MsarEl3HEUFnsTYIqeD8hLuJjeUGH_EXJRqh6n2-hdApO67IPRE3Eoy4rpAPZEsHrGP08WfFicjRr49PEaJlnsxVXsTxaO6smKWiCwh4JiFDYy7y-kw9orvRqyvR_8aVh1XhNFktUhtyRBOSXqN-nGxPnjD2C3lJgQAOck2i8lt_gcEiY2xqGiS0Qz-6119cRr3R2PkEXMFoVRL_8gK94OckenUg-OmIWydfJH66c_RaSGEsgozOjHCAiSiA0N2kzH_juBsLxH4CwR9VYm0lVitLVnoauVloz3fdm-so7uJ5ccFPPbfhCdKIOTwOSYxjVBJh_QWOz-BcfOeCfXIxP9PZ7DTsn2Esz2zT-hQgElOy01j0_rYfNOj92EEqRjbWGdtSr4onkAsQqIFhKJlSFQ7TbemgO6cliRWmB2Hje4XVJSVJBAv-qOh397sgCm4QYJknue0XejvIFSxaxGaoockQsA8VTl1Wtpj_Up1alKpm1tyIwVOEuQCdpy5XreSI3KxnnkKS17Ged1IT9RTL-F6X8xvgoig9rp00T9YnrXB4yNsLHkPkYHFPI4IN_O9ULrDSg_p6lN6ulc2DNY0ap-z9VSnOwKZuqnxyXxw5ymvraieRC.0fJ38Gr299EfDubtBpuRYg"
decryption_key = "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"

decrypted_token = jwe.decrypt(encrypted_jwe, base64.urlsafe_b64decode(decryption_key))

.net6 equivalent for simple python code.
I try this way
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using AesGcm = System.Security.Cryptography.AesGcm;

        static string DecryptJwe2(string jweToken, string decryptionKey)
        {

            var privateKeyPemBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(decryptionKey); // PEM string here
            var privateKeyPem = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(privateKeyPemBytes);

            var jweTokenBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(SafeBase64String(jweToken)); // Your PEM string here
            jweToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(jweTokenBytes);

            // 1. Import Private Key
            PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(privateKeyPem));
            var keyPair = pemReader.ReadObject();

            // 2. Decrypt with RSA Private Key
            var decryptor = new RsaEngine();
            decryptor.Init(false, (Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.ICipherParameters)keyPair); // False for decryption with private key

            byte[] decodedToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jweToken); // Assuming Base64 encoding
            byte[] decryptedToken = decryptor.ProcessBlock(decodedToken, 0, decodedToken.Length);   // Fail with input too large for RSA cipher

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedToken);

        }

        static string SafeBase64String(string base64String)
        {
            base64String = base64String.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/'); // Replace Base64url characters with Base64 characters

            // Add padding if necessary
            int padding = base64String.Length % 4;
            if (padding > 0) base64String += new string('=', 4 - padding);
            return base64String;
        }



...I'm trying to decrypt a jwt token in .Net 6 without success... SO is not a code delivery service. Please post your .NET code and describe the problem.

It's a simple question.
I've seen others like this.
Can you give me an alternative to this code in C#?
If necessary, I can post the various attempts I made, but I didn't want to overcomplicate the issue.
In Python, using Jose, it's as simple as that. I expected that in C# it would also be simple using the c# jose library, but unfortunately it seems not.
My hope is that someone said it, in C# it's also simple, just this:
using jose.xxxxx
decrypted_token = jwe.decrypt(encrypt.....
Honestly, I don't really understand your observation.

Without writing the code... Look at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens and JsonWebTokenHandler.  System.Security.Cryptography contains various algorithm implementations of AssymetricAlgorithm, which has methods like ImportFromPem to get the key. JsonWebTokenHandler has methods such as DecryptToken and ValidateToken etc. It should not be too much work. You can use https://jwt.io/ to inspect the token you have, and understand what algorithms are used. This is what I do in a similar scenario, creating tokens with jose, and validating them in .NET .

Honestly, I don't see what's so hard to understand about this. Questions that show no effort of their own and simply ask for a port of a code without sharing their own code are usually closed on SO.

Ok.
I don't agree 100%, but i'll will put more information.
Thanks

...in .Net 6 without success... Can you provide more specifics? Do you get errors or exceptions when you run your code, and if so please post the full details of these?

It is most convenient to use a JOSE library to decrypt the encrypted token, e.g. jose-jwt. The code is as simple as the Python code. The PEM encoded key can be imported on .NET 6 with native methods. A possible implementation is:
using Jose;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

...

// Key import
string pkcs8PemB64 = "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";
string pkcs8Pem = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(pkcs8PemB64));
RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportFromPem(pkcs8Pem);

// JWE decryption
string token = "eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUC0yNTYiLCJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0.IDqmx1u_8Jd6XofUyTubUEAMWw9Zu2reF3JJsijRICCFRG_Dcb15pOs61DQx8DwhQbVSWA-Zbt_xlJ5dTtaC_JlP8PRFYbAkhHdOtPVUuEKIx9OEm5DOF5hi-d-VJd5JOrDaGgSSlz59vQHgY8whGzNTbJhfjyKwkz-uaEiyb8kblDAVd-mjBPcL1_1MOpMfyfuXgroi3RiR--zyjNgOUZ2R3hKZmlISAuRjrIJB8xKZntRu3GtJczX6jCgJFvWAYqrlHtMoRLuGrcOsM3WDx7urX9ur90A7idGuq2rj8aaOg2Ld-sAMfhoS0jKwK4Gj0CumAza4QvpZPVjVWaep7A.XlSCfsZVmku1CGxK.mCbCvPxsdWRDw_ZmlMtETrX_TLdxQQ0lxqFfUaX6Pv8TCChFodZb9PE0kUycW1pTTPYYbGh2d40CYgvLAMP_c1me27uFYOsy3P3CDoULKR-MNU4f19nCuRlMgWeMqG0e7GVmGQwem4TpcA4CZTdd5V0kzXBLm4ns3i3NlNoNrhfG7pW87Eb0oYo9s1wvALDmvgiFUb-apxUqJXaSIZ51pSSwkyPSLPtd_tq-8weNNuyf9SBsQUWEjRn8CHtmjuKhKOP4TaJYqjsA80ydLUUhmogrMzpqEgahitZ1ygDwv2UYwzykt5kklZ63OGPdZrYosM3t0kpi4CP9F5gyvx-jOiiMLcdz46d0t8315H9HEJW_Du3BkmW6IQ1r__mlrp2ylNMTVT7_oh_WQHUc2HEszJ-yELUSd0RM96vgXUGjWlwfex9hLYI2VaMSZ00MsarEl3HEUFnsTYIqeD8hLuJjeUGH_EXJRqh6n2-hdApO67IPRE3Eoy4rpAPZEsHrGP08WfFicjRr49PEaJlnsxVXsTxaO6smKWiCwh4JiFDYy7y-kw9orvRqyvR_8aVh1XhNFktUhtyRBOSXqN-nGxPnjD2C3lJgQAOck2i8lt_gcEiY2xqGiS0Qz-6119cRr3R2PkEXMFoVRL_8gK94OckenUg-OmIWydfJH66c_RaSGEsgozOjHCAiSiA0N2kzH_juBsLxH4CwR9VYm0lVitLVnoauVloz3fdm-so7uJ5ccFPPbfhCdKIOTwOSYxjVBJh_QWOz-BcfOeCfXIxP9PZ7DTsn2Esz2zT-hQgElOy01j0_rYfNOj92EEqRjbWGdtSr4onkAsQqIFhKJlSFQ7TbemgO6cliRWmB2Hje4XVJSVJBAv-qOh397sgCm4QYJknue0XejvIFSxaxGaoockQsA8VTl1Wtpj_Up1alKpm1tyIwVOEuQCdpy5XreSI3KxnnkKS17Ged1IT9RTL-F6X8xvgoig9rp00T9YnrXB4yNsLHkPkYHFPI4IN_O9ULrDSg_p6lN6ulc2DNY0ap-z9VSnOwKZuqnxyXxw5ymvraieRC.0fJ38Gr299EfDubtBpuRYg";
JweToken decToken = Jose.JWE.Decrypt(token, rsa);
Console.WriteLine(decToken.Plaintext); // eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.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.hejtpz-weznhqyzHrf307RxAI09wa6CpcoyTeoOHreY

The decrypted payload is a nested JWT.

Also possible, but much more cumbersome, is decryption without a JOSE library, as you are probably trying to do in your code (albeit incomplete and with a number of flaws).
Here, the algorithms involved must first be determined from the header, which are then to be used for decryption: In this case, A256GCM for decrypting the content and RSA-OAEP-256 for decrypting the AES key:
// Key import
...

// Get aad, cek, iv, ciphertext and tag
string token = "eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUC0yNTYiLCJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0.IDqmx1u_8Jd6XofUyTubUEAMWw9Zu2reF3JJsijRICCFRG_Dcb15pOs61DQx8DwhQbVSWA-Zbt_xlJ5dTtaC_JlP8PRFYbAkhHdOtPVUuEKIx9OEm5DOF5hi-d-VJd5JOrDaGgSSlz59vQHgY8whGzNTbJhfjyKwkz-uaEiyb8kblDAVd-mjBPcL1_1MOpMfyfuXgroi3RiR--zyjNgOUZ2R3hKZmlISAuRjrIJB8xKZntRu3GtJczX6jCgJFvWAYqrlHtMoRLuGrcOsM3WDx7urX9ur90A7idGuq2rj8aaOg2Ld-sAMfhoS0jKwK4Gj0CumAza4QvpZPVjVWaep7A.XlSCfsZVmku1CGxK.mCbCvPxsdWRDw_ZmlMtETrX_TLdxQQ0lxqFfUaX6Pv8TCChFodZb9PE0kUycW1pTTPYYbGh2d40CYgvLAMP_c1me27uFYOsy3P3CDoULKR-MNU4f19nCuRlMgWeMqG0e7GVmGQwem4TpcA4CZTdd5V0kzXBLm4ns3i3NlNoNrhfG7pW87Eb0oYo9s1wvALDmvgiFUb-apxUqJXaSIZ51pSSwkyPSLPtd_tq-8weNNuyf9SBsQUWEjRn8CHtmjuKhKOP4TaJYqjsA80ydLUUhmogrMzpqEgahitZ1ygDwv2UYwzykt5kklZ63OGPdZrYosM3t0kpi4CP9F5gyvx-jOiiMLcdz46d0t8315H9HEJW_Du3BkmW6IQ1r__mlrp2ylNMTVT7_oh_WQHUc2HEszJ-yELUSd0RM96vgXUGjWlwfex9hLYI2VaMSZ00MsarEl3HEUFnsTYIqeD8hLuJjeUGH_EXJRqh6n2-hdApO67IPRE3Eoy4rpAPZEsHrGP08WfFicjRr49PEaJlnsxVXsTxaO6smKWiCwh4JiFDYy7y-kw9orvRqyvR_8aVh1XhNFktUhtyRBOSXqN-nGxPnjD2C3lJgQAOck2i8lt_gcEiY2xqGiS0Qz-6119cRr3R2PkEXMFoVRL_8gK94OckenUg-OmIWydfJH66c_RaSGEsgozOjHCAiSiA0N2kzH_juBsLxH4CwR9VYm0lVitLVnoauVloz3fdm-so7uJ5ccFPPbfhCdKIOTwOSYxjVBJh_QWOz-BcfOeCfXIxP9PZ7DTsn2Esz2zT-hQgElOy01j0_rYfNOj92EEqRjbWGdtSr4onkAsQqIFhKJlSFQ7TbemgO6cliRWmB2Hje4XVJSVJBAv-qOh397sgCm4QYJknue0XejvIFSxaxGaoockQsA8VTl1Wtpj_Up1alKpm1tyIwVOEuQCdpy5XreSI3KxnnkKS17Ged1IT9RTL-F6X8xvgoig9rp00T9YnrXB4yNsLHkPkYHFPI4IN_O9ULrDSg_p6lN6ulc2DNY0ap-z9VSnOwKZuqnxyXxw5ymvraieRC.0fJ38Gr299EfDubtBpuRYg";
string[] tokenParts = token.Split('.');
byte[] aad = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tokenParts[0]);
byte[] cek = DecodeBase64url(tokenParts[1]);
byte[] iv = DecodeBase64url(tokenParts[2]);
byte[] ciphertext = DecodeBase64url(tokenParts[3]);
byte[] tag = DecodeBase64url(tokenParts[4]);

// Decrypt cek with RSA-OAEP-256
byte[] key = rsa.Decrypt(cek, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);

// Decrypt payload with A256GCM
AesGcm aesGcm = new AesGcm(key);
byte[] plaintext = new byte[ciphertext.Length];
aesGcm.Decrypt(iv, ciphertext, tag, plaintext, aad);

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintext)); // eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.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.hejtpz-weznhqyzHrf307RxAI09wa6CpcoyTeoOHreY

where DecodeBase64url() is a custom method for Base64url decoding (e.g. from here) or from a library (e.g. here).

Note that it is actually not necessary to Base64 encode a PEM encoded key, as the PEM encoding is already a text representation of an ASN.1/DER encoded key.

It works.
I was close in the tests I did, but I didn't put the rsa here:
JweToken decToken = Jose.JWE.Decrypt(token, rsa);
thank you very much @Topaco
